# Simple blog in CSS and HTML only

Tags: html, css, blogs

I have a simple html/css-only static website on which I would like to add a blog. Comments and RSS aren't necessary.

Now, how do I do that, without having to write all my entries in pure html?

My website consists of a vertical menu and an area to the right of it, where all the content goes on each page. I would like a blog inside that area on the blog page, so a blog on a separate page with its own layout is not what I'm looking for.

Googling this doesn't really help me much since the majority of the hits are on sites offering blog services.

Thanks in advance, I hope I'm not being too difficult. Please leave some feedback on my question if you think there are things I should have tried out before asking.

Comment: you need database for keep the comment history or article.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i understand what you want the answer is that ist is not possible in pure html and css. With only Html and css you can not make a blog (if you dont want to edit the source everytime you write an entry and have to make a new file for each entry and so on).

You need some code (php or so) that is able to store and load the entrys into your site.
Html and css are not meant to make things working. With Html you define the elements so that they are structed and then with css you "style" your work. But for the task of a blog (i think you want an editor for the text on the site, the ability to edit, delete, more than one site and so on) you need something like php or aps.net that is able to "interact".